# Admin Onboarding

Tags: onboarding, administration, view

Seeking guidance from the community. Im designing the onboarding flow for an alpha release of a SAAS product aimed at employee engagement. One of the primary persona is an *HR admin*, who most likely is the primary account holder, who will be tasked to setup the whole account. My IA is split into `user navigation` and `admin navigation` sections. My initial though was to onboard the admin like a regular user where by showing them around the workspace as a regular user, also seeding some dummy data so that they are not entering an empty room. While doing this, I planned to give various nudges at each module to introduce them to the corresponding module administration in the settings section, from where they can return with ease to each module. I also thought of creating *Setup progress indicator* (%) and *tasks lists* to nudge the admin user.

While doing reviews with stakeholders, *another suggestion* came up to land the admin to the settings page itself (an overview of different module settings as the segway page into the section). The argument is that the admin gets a clear view of all the offerings in an uncluttered view, while clearly give them an indication that they are in an `admin view`, and an easy switch to view the `employee view`. There are some challenges to this approach from a layout and other requirements that followed up, but I wanted to know if this is the right approach.

In my mind, besides maybe the initial few days of setting up, the *HR admin* too is a regular employee, who might benefit from entering the workspace through the same doors. Hence, showing the workspace like a regular user felt like the right approach. Am i being biased here? Have you all come across apps that does this efficiently?

Comment: After the onboarding period, will the HR admin be primarily focused on admin tasks, or regular user tasks?

Answer (score 1):

During the signup flow, could you ask the user what their role is and then customise the onboarding experience for them?

For example, you could create two checklists of tasks—one for admins and one for users. If someone identifies as an admin, you could show them both lists (separated into groups). If someone is a regular user, you just show them the second group of tasks.

[image: Checklist of tasks]